# MATLAB: Quickest Way To Convert Characters to A Custom Set Numbers and Back

Tags: string, matlab

I'm looking for a quick way to convert a large character array of lowercase letters, spaces and periods into a set of integers and vice-versa in MATLAB.

Usually I would use the double and char functions, but I would like to use a special set of integers to represent each letter (so that 'a' matches with '1', 'b' matches with '2'.... 'z' matches with 26, ' ' matches with 27, and '.' matches with 28)

The current method that I have is:

```
text = 'quick brown fox jumps over dirty dog';
alphabet ='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz .';

converted_text = double(text);
converted_alphabet = double(alphabet);

numbers = nan(28,1)

for i = 1:28
     numbers(converted_text(i)==converted_alphabet(i)) = i;
end

newtext = nan(size(numbers))

for i = 1:size(numbers,1)
   newtext(numbers==i) = alphabet(i)
end
```

Unfortunately this takes quite a bit of time for large arrays, and I'm wondering if there is a quicker way to do this in MATLAB?

Comment: do you mean that for a given string, you want to replace 'a' with the number 1, all the way to 'z' replaced with 26? what about characters outside your alphabet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy way is to use `ismember()`:

```
[~,pos] = ismember(text,alphabet)
```

Or use the implicit conversion carried out by `-`:

```
out = text - 'a' + 1;
```

note that blanks will have -64 and full stops -50, which means that you will need:

```
out(out == -64) = 27;
out(out == -50) = 28;
```

### Speed considerations:

For **small** sized arrays the latter solution is slightly faster IF you are happy to leave blanks and full stops with their negative index.

For **big** arrays, on my machine 1e4 times longer, the latter solution is twice faster than `ismember()`.

### Going back:

```
alphabet(out)
```

Comment: but, as it is now, don't you just see if any alphabet element is within the statement (its spot actually)?

Comment: @fpe Yes, but it is what the OP wants, no? "*so that 'a' matches with '1', 'b' matches with '2'.... 'z' matches with 26, ' ' matches with 27, and '.' matches with 28*"

Comment: yep, my bad...your approach is flawless :)

Comment: @OlegKomarov: perhaps you could use `isstrprop` to deal with punctuations and other special characters. Also you might want to call `lower` or `upper`